# After loading a trained model in torch, how to use this loaded model to classify new inputs?

Tags: deep-learning, torch, conv-neural-network

I am reproducing the work "Character-level Convolutional Networks for Text Classification" with the [code](https://github.com/zhangxiangxiao/Crepe) provided by the authors.

When I finished training process, I got the dumped model stored in "sequential_50000_1458876622.t7b" and its visualized image is [sequential_50000_1458876622.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TL6lG.png).

I have been trying to figure out how to apply the dumped model after it has been trained. I'm not sure how to use it on new unclassified data. Here's what I've tried in torch7:

```
th> model=torch.load("sequential_5000_1458675427.t7b")
th> model
```

It shows:

```
nn.Sequential {
[input -> (1) -> (2) -> (3) -> (4) -> (5) -> (6) -> (7) -> (8) -> (9) -> (10) -> (11) -> (12) -> (13) -> (14) -> (15) -> (16) -> (17) -> (18) -> (19) -> (20) -> (21) -> (22) -> (23) -> (24) -> output]
  (1): nn.TemporalConvolution
  (2): nn.Threshold
  (3): nn.TemporalMaxPooling
  (4): nn.TemporalConvolution
  (5): nn.Threshold
  (6): nn.TemporalMaxPooling
  (7): nn.TemporalConvolution
  (8): nn.Threshold
  (9): nn.TemporalConvolution
  (10): nn.Threshold
  (11): nn.TemporalConvolution
  (12): nn.Threshold
  (13): nn.TemporalConvolution
  (14): nn.Threshold
  (15): nn.TemporalMaxPooling
  (16): nn.Reshape(8704)
  (17): nn.Linear(8704 -> 1024)
  (18): nn.Threshold
  (19): nn.Dropout(0.000000)
  (20): nn.Linear(1024 -> 1024)
  (21): nn.Threshold
  (22): nn.Dropout(0.000000)
  (23): nn.Linear(1024 -> 14)
  (24): nn.LogSoftMax
}
```

I have no idea about how to use this model to predict new unclassified data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the desired case through the model's forward pass; catch the returned predicted values:

```
score = model:forward(input_case)
```

Depending on your model's return parameters, the score could be a single classification or a vector of top choices; configure your reporting accordingly.

If you need a more complete example, try searching for "torch7 score tutorial".  To get you started more immediately, [here](https://github.com/torch/tutorials/blob/master/2_supervised/5_test.lua) is a relatively succinct example under the Torch tutorials on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks, Prune. I will run the proper 'score' code and follow your suggestions to learn the tutorial.